# ATTRIBUTE ERROR : AttributeError at /menu/register/ ----- 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Here's the full code. This error occurs when I try to build the login and register form!

**ERROR**`

```
AttributeError at /menu/register/
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/menu/register/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
Exception Location: /Users/ambuj/Documents/GitHub/TrailPOS/pos/menu/forms.py in clean_username, line 70
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/ambuj/Documents/GitHub/TrailPOS/pos',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.10.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
Server time:    Wed, 14 Jun 2017 10:44:22 +0000`
```

**My views.py**

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import dish
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from .mixins import FormUserNeededMixin
from .mixins import UserOwnerMixin
from .models import category
from .models import discount
from .models import tax
from .models import Cash
from .models import Order
from .forms import dishModelForm
from .forms import categoryModelForm
from .forms import discountModelForm
from .forms import taxModelForm
from .forms import UserRegisterModelForm
import logging
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.core.exceptions import MultipleObjectsReturned
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

import json


# Create your views here.
User = get_user_model()

discList = {}
taxList = {}

class UserRegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'menu/user_register.html'
    form_class = UserRegisterModelForm
    success_url = '/login'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        new_user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email)
        new_user.set_password(password)
        new_user.save()
        return super(UserRegisterView, self).form_valid(form)


class DiscountListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    queryset = discount.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DiscountListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context

class DiscountCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = discountModelForm
    template_name = 'menu/adddiscount.html'
    success_url = "/menu/create_discount/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(DiscountCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

class DiscountDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    queryset = discount.objects.all()

class DiscountUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, UpdateView):
    queryset = discount.objects.all()
    form_class = discountModelForm
    template_name = 'menu/discount_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("discount_list")

class DiscountDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, DeleteView):
    model = discount
    template_name = 'menu/delete_confirm.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("discount_list")


class CategoryDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    queryset = category.objects.all()


class CategoryCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = categoryModelForm
    template_name = 'menu/addcategory.html'
    success_url = "/menu/create_category/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CategoryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)


class CategoryListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    queryset = category.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context


class CategoryUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, UpdateView):
    queryset = category.objects.all()
    form_class = categoryModelForm
    template_name = 'menu/category_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("category_list")


class CategoryDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, DeleteView):
    model = category
    template_name = 'menu/delete_confirm.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("category_list")





class DishCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, FormUserNeededMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = dishModelForm
    template_name = 'menu/adddish.html'
    success_url = "/menu/dishes/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(DishCreateView, self).form_valid(form)


class DishDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    queryset = dish.objects.all()

    #def get_object(self):
    #    print(self.kwargs)
    #    pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
    #    obj = get_object_or_404(dish, pk=pk)
    #    return obj


class DishListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    queryset = dish.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DishListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context

class DishUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, UpdateView):
    queryset = dish.objects.all()
    form_class = dishModelForm
    template_name = 'menu/dish_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("dish_list")

class DishDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, DeleteView):
    model = dish
    template_name = 'menu/delete_confirm.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("dish_list")





class TaxCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = taxModelForm
    template_name = 'menu/addtax.html'
    success_url = "/menu/create_tax/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(TaxCreateView, self).form_valid(form)


class TaxListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    queryset = tax.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(TaxListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context


class TaxDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    queryset = tax.objects.all()

class TaxUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, UpdateView):
    queryset = tax.objects.all()
    form_class = taxModelForm
    template_name = 'menu/tax_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("tax_list")

class TaxDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, DeleteView):
    model = tax
    template_name = 'menu/delete_confirm.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("tax_list")



def order(request):
    product_list = dish.objects.all
    template = loader.get_template('menu/order.html')
    context = {
            'product_list': product_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def addition(request, operation):
    cash,_ = Cash.objects.get_or_create(id=0)
    succesfully_payed = False
    payment_error = False
    amountAdded = 0
    try:
        currentOrder,_ = Order.objects.get_or_create(order_user=request.user.username)
    except MultipleObjectsReturned:
        currentOrder = list(Order.objects.filter(order_user=request.user.username))[0]
        logging.warn("there were MultipleObjectsReturned")
    if currentOrder is None:
        raise Exception("current Order is empty")
    if operation:
        if operation.isdecimal():
            tmplist = json.loads(currentOrder.order_list)
            tmpproduct = dish.objects.get(pk=operation)
            tmpdiscount = discount.objects.get(discountDish=tmpproduct)
            if tmpdiscount.discountApp:
                sub = tmpdiscount.discountRate
                sub = Decimal(sub / 100) * tmpproduct.dishFullPrice
            else:
                sub = 0
            tmptax = tax.objects.get(taxDish=tmpproduct)
            if tmptax.taxApp:
                add = tmptax.taxRate
                add = Decimal(add / 100) * tmpproduct.dishFullPrice
            else:
                add = 0
            tmplist.append(tmpproduct.dishName)
            currentOrder.order_list = json.dumps(tmplist)
            currentOrder.order_totalprice = currentOrder.order_totalprice + tmpproduct.dishFullPrice - Decimal(sub) + Decimal(add)
            if not tmpdiscount.discountApp:
                bd = tmpdiscount.discountRate
                bd = Decimal(bd / 100) * currentOrder.order_totalprice
                currentOrder.order_totalprice = currentOrder.order_totalprice -bd
                discList[tmpdiscount.discountName] = tmpdiscount.discountRate
            tmptax = tax.objects.get(taxDish=tmpproduct)
            if not tmptax.taxApp:
                bt = tmptax.taxRate
                bt = Decimal(bt / 100) * tmpproduct.dishFullPrice
                currentOrder.order_totalprice = currentOrder.order_totalprice + bt
                taxList[tmptax.taxName] = tmptax.taxRate
            currentOrder.save()
        elif operation == "reset":
            currentOrder.order_list = json.dumps(list())
            currentOrder.order_totalprice = 0
            discList.clear()
            taxList.clear()
            currentOrder.save()
        elif operation == "payed":
            for x in json.loads(currentOrder.order_list):
                tmpproduct = dish.objects.get(dishName=x)
                tmpproduct.save()
                cash.cash_amount = cash.cash_amount + tmpproduct.dishFullPrice
                amountAdded = amountAdded + tmpproduct.dishFullPrice
                cash.save()
            currentOrder.order_list = json.dumps(list())
            currentOrder.order_totalprice = 0
            currentOrder.save()
            succesfully_payed = True
        else:
            tmpproduct = dish.objects.filter(dishName = operation).first()
            if tmpproduct is not None:
                tmplist = json.loads(currentOrder.order_list)
                i = tmplist.index(tmpproduct.dishName)
                del tmplist[i]
                currentOrder.order_list = json.dumps(tmplist)
                currentOrder.order_totalprice = currentOrder.order_totalprice - tmpproduct.dishFullPrice
                if currentOrder.order_totalprice < 0:
                    logging.warn("prices below 0!")
                    currentOrder.order_totalprice = 0
                currentOrder.save()

    totalprice = currentOrder.order_totalprice
    order_list = json.loads(currentOrder.order_list)
    template = loader.get_template('menu/addition.html')
    context = {
            'order_list': order_list,
            'totalprice': totalprice,
            'cash': cash,
            'discList': discList,
            'taxList': taxList,
            'succesfully_payed': succesfully_payed,
            'payment_error': payment_error,
            'amount_added': amountAdded,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))



#def dish_detail_view(request, id=1):
#    obj = dish.objects.get(id=id)
#    print(obj)
#    context = {
#     "object": obj
#    }
#    return render(request, "menu/detail_view.html", context)

#def dish_list_view(request):
#    queryset = dish.objects.all()
#    print(queryset)
#    for obj in queryset:
#        print(obj.dishName)
#    context = {
#        "object_list": queryset
#    }
#    return render(request, "menu/list_view.html", context)
```

**My Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class category(models.Model):
    categoryName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryName


class dish(models.Model):
    BOOL_CHOICES = ((True,'Veg'),(False,'Non-Veg'))
    dishid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    dishName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dishCuisine = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dishContent = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    dishType = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
    dishCategory = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dishHalfPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=3,default=0)
    dishFullPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=3,default=0)
    dishCostPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=3,default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dishID

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dishName

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.full_clean()
        super(dish, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    #def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #    dishName = self.dishName
    #    if dishName == "":
    #        raise ValidationError("Cannot be empty")
    #    return super(dish, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)


class discount(models.Model):
    APPLICATION_CHOICES = ((True, 'Single Item'), (False, 'Final Bill'))
    discountName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    discountDish = models.ForeignKey(dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    discountRate = models.IntegerField()
    discountDescription = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    discountApp = models.BooleanField(choices=APPLICATION_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.discountName


class tax(models.Model):
    APPLICATION_CHOICES = ((True, 'Single Item'), (False, 'Final Bill'))
    taxName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    taxDish = models.ForeignKey(dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    taxRate = models.IntegerField()
    taxDescription = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    taxApp = models.BooleanField(choices=APPLICATION_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.taxName


class Order(models.Model):
    order_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order_list = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    order_totalprice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=3,default=0)


class Cash(models.Model):
    cash_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3,default=0)
```

**My Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import dish
from .models import category
from .models import discount
from .models import tax
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model

class dishModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = dish
        fields = [
            "dishName",
            "dishCuisine",
            "dishContent",
            "dishType",
            "dishCategory",
            "dishHalfPrice",
            "dishFullPrice",
            "dishCostPrice"
        ]


class categoryModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = category
        fields = [
            "categoryName"
        ]

class discountModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = discount
        fields = [
            "discountName",
            "discountDish",
            "discountRate",
            "discountDescription",
            "discountApp"
        ]

class taxModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = tax
        fields = [
            "taxName",
            "taxDish",
            "taxRate",
            "taxDescription",
            "taxApp"
        ]

class UserRegisterModelForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)


    def clean_password2(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password must match")
        return password2

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if User.objects.filter(username__icontains=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This username is taken")
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if User.objects.filter(email__icontains=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email is already registered.")
        return email
```

**My html file**

```
{% extends "menu/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <form class='form' method='POST' action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Register" />
  </form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called `get_user_model` when you reference it in your forms.py.

```
User = get_user_model()
```

And please, do not cut and paste your text multiple times; there's a reason SO requires you to write a minimum amount of text compared to your code; in your case, you've posted tons of code that is unrelated to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir! Appreciate it!